# Unable to log in to any Stack Exchange site with OpenID and Safari

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, openid, safari

I'm trying to log in with the same OpenID provider I've used for years (pip.verisignlabs.com). Here are the results when using Safari 8.0.2 (10600.2.5)

1. I go to the SE login page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/login),
2. I click "More Login Options"
3. I then either click the verisign button or manually enter the URL (both have the same effect)
4. I'm redirected to the verisign page as per usual and enter my credentials
5. Instead of being redirected back to SE, I'm sent to the PIP homepage (https://pip.verisignlabs.com)

Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) seems to work fine. What's Safari's problem? How can I debug it?

Comment: Let's start with "is this only a problem when you have to enter your credentials during the authentication workflow?". Is it possible to sign into Verisign before you attempt logging in on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I logged into Verisign, successfully first, and I'm having the same problem with FF 36.0. Curiously when I try the URL method, SE re-writes the URL with a space in it. I'm not sure if that's cause or effect of the login failure.